Как стать хорошим редактором?
Подробнее об инструментах редактирования.

Часть информации для этой статьи взята из связанных статей:

"Почему кто-то может редактировать мои сообщения? Как работает система редактирования?"
"Коллективная правка — залог качественного содержимого"
"Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?"
"Почему предлагаемые правки были отклонены?"


Здравствуй, пользователь Stack Overflow на русском!
Вне зависимости от того, являетесь ли вы новым пользователем данного сайта, или же вы присутствуете на нём продолжительное время, вы могли заметить, что на сайте:

Есть те, кто задаёт вопросы и публикует ответы;
Есть те, кто отвечает за порядком (модераторы со значком "♦" возле отображаемого имени);
И есть те, кто корректирует (правит) вопросы/ответы (так называемые "редакторы").

Безусловно, это очень упрощённая картина того, как работают сайты Stack (подробнее про механизмы работы вы можете узнать во вкладках "Справка" и "Привилегии").

В этой статье мы поговорим как раз таки о редакторах — тех, кто занимается правками.
Из редакторов можно выделить тех, кто:

Занимается правками;
Проверяет и утверждает правки (так называемые "проверяющие").

Проверяющие — это пользователи с 2 000 и более баллами репутации, которые рассматривают правки, предлагаемые пользователями с репутацией менее 2 000. Именно проверяющие решают, что сделать с правкой: принять/отклонить/править/принять и править/отклонить и править.

У вас, как у человека, который хочет заняться правками вопросов/ответов других пользователей, могли возникнуть следующе вопросы:

Что позволительно, а что недопустимо делать редактору?
Какие вопросы/ответы не стоит править?
Что можно улучшить в вопросе/ответе?
Как происходит процесс принятия предлагаемой правки?

Если да, то эта статья предназначена как раз для вас!

Возможно имеет смысл пост назвать без "начинающим"?

@SwaD, спасибо за замечание! Я планировал именно написать "для начинающих", поскольку тот, кто наберёт 2 000 баллов репутации, как по мне, уже будет разбираться "во всех тонкостях кухни"))

Ну как по мне, что бы стать начинающим, надо просто начать редактировать посты. А вот что бы стать "хорошим", надо освоить те "правила", что указаны вами в ответе. Если их усвоить, то ты уже не начинающий :) А вопрос баллов репы - это дело наживное

Мое дело предложить, ваше принять во внимание. Повторюсь еще раз(мое личное мнение): нельзя ранжировать редакторов по количеству баллов репы на опытных и начинающих. Хороший редактор может быть и до 2к репы, просто ограничение платформы не даст внести правку без проверки другими участниками

@SwaD, вы правы, заголовок и содержимое теперь изменены))

Что же, уважаемый редактор, давай начнём наш тур!
1. Ограничения для редакторов
А начать стоит с того, что непозволительно делать редактору.
Непозволительно следующее:
1. Вносить правку, искажающую суть изначального сообщения.
Представим себе ситуацию, что человек написал в вопросе код, содержащий ошибки. Например, отсутствует запятая при перечислении аргументов в какой-либо функции:

<...>
def func(x y)
<...>

Вы могли подумать: "Поставлю я запятую, тут же ошибка!"
Я вам отвечу: "Внимательно прочтите то, что автор написал дальше!"
А дальше в тексте вопроса написано:

У меня по моему коду выводится ошибка:
  File "main.py", line 4
    def func(x y):
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Как быть? Что не так?

Если бы вы поставили запятую в функции, то вопрос потерял бы свой изначальный смысл!
Этот вопрос относятся к "вопросам низкого качества". Такие вопросы обычно закрываются по тревоге по причине "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой".
Но суть не в этом, суть в том, что вы должны вносить правки внимательно ознакомившись со всем текстом целиком!

Если вы видите банальную ошибку в коде вопроса: напишите об этом автору в комментариях! (но помните, что комментировать вопросы/ответы вы можете при достижении репутации в 50 баллов)

Если вы знаете, как исправить ошибку в коде — не правьте изначальный код в вопросе, вместо этого ответьте на вопрос автора!

Помните о том, что удаление символа или буквы в тексте вопроса или в коде могут его кардинально поменять. К этому нужно подходить серьёзно!


Приведу другой пример:
В вопросе дан следующий код:

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        <...>

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }

        <...>
    }


Что мы тут видим: отсутствует закрывающая скобка "}" в коде. Читаем, что пишет автор дальше:

Приложение компилируется, но программа не выполняет <...>

Что мы узнали:

Программа компилируется;
Проблема в обработке данных.

Это значит, что автор забыл дописать закрывающую скобку "}", или же она не отображается вследствие проблем с форматированием — такое бывает, если символы "`" находятся вплотную к скобке (так, например: }```).
В таком случае добавление закрывающей скобки уместно.
Как видите, всё зависит от контекста.
2. Удалять из сообщения детали, которые дополняют основную мысль сообщения.
Например, автор написал:

Мой код работает, но только на Windows, на Linux он уже не работает.

При этом автор не указал подробности, указан только код.
"Удалю эту ничего незначащую строку!" — скажите вы.
"Не удаляйте детали автора!" — отвечу я.
Этот вопрос тоже является проблемным. Может быть, что это строка автора является лишней, а может она и не лишняя! Спросите об этом у автора в комментариях напрямую! Если автор не соизволит наполнить вопрос подробностями, то скорее всего такой вопрос будет закрыт.
В любом случае у редактора нет полномочий менять содержимое вопроса.
3. Удалять/вносить детали без опоры на идею/текст автора.
Это касается неточных формулировок в тексте.
Допустим, автор вопроса написал следующее:

Не работает класс подтипов, как мне починить подключение к базе данных?

Или:

У меня структура классов не юзается, что делать?

Тот, кто обладает экстрасенсорными способностями, поймет, что имел в виду автор. Для всех остальных будет проблематично понять суть проблемы.
Задайте уточняющий комментарий автору или поставьте тревогу на вопросе по причине "Непонятна суть вопроса" или "Необходимо сфокусироваться на проблеме" и т. п.
Не пытайтесь "расшифровать" то, что имел в виду автор!
*4. Не пытайтесь улучшить изначально плохой вопрос.
Это не строгое правило, но рекомендация. Вы можете улучшить форматирование кода, исправить правописание в тексте, но если вы понимаете, что вопрос изначально плохой (и он будет закрыт), то зачем вам это делать? Право остаётся за вами, но это будет бесполезным действием с точки зрения прилагаемых вами усилий по исправлению — такие вопросы должен править сам автор.
По поводу перевода вопросов/ответов — хорошая дискуссия по этой теме в статье "Можно ли переводить вопрос/ответ на основном сайте?"
Если вкратце, то переводить это:

I have this code

Можно и нужно.
Но если вопрос объёмный, а подробности на нём на иностранном языке — не пытайтесь переводить его с помощью переводчика. Вместо этого напишите в комментариях: "переведите ваш вопрос/ответ" или поставьте тревогу "Вопрос следует закрыть, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке".

Были рассмотрены примеры вопросов, но вы должны понимать, что такие же правила действуют и для правки ответов.
Помните, что любому пользователю, имеющему большое количество отклонённых правок, будет заблокирована возможность внесения правок на 7 дней. Поэтому соблюдение этих принципов — священный долг хорошего редактора!
2. Возможности редакторов
Теперь поговорим с вами о том, что можно и нужно делать редактору:

Удалять чувствительную информацию в тексте/коде (токены, персональную/конфиденциальную/секретную информацию);
Удалять "воду" из текста (информацию, не относящуюся к проблеме и к тексту вопроса) по типу приветствий, просьб о помощи и т. д. (подробнее об этом вы можете прочесть в одноимённой статье "Приветствия, подписи, мольбы, благодарности, лирические отступления, истории из жизни");
Исправлять ошибки правописания в тексте;
Уточнять и/или объяснять сообщения (без изменения его смысла);
Вносить информацию, которая находится в комментариях, для обеспечения целостности сообщения;
Добавлять актуальную информацию, ресурсы и гиперссылки, относящиеся к сообщению;
Исправлять небольшие ошибки, опечатки;
Добавлять отсутствующее форматирование и Markdown, а именно:

помещать код в блок кода (с помощью трёх символов "`" (или "~") в начале и конце кода);
сокращать ссылки:

сайт https://ru.stackoverflow.com → сайт


помещать цитируемую информацию в блок цитата (с помощью символа ">");
и т. д.


Исправлять табуляцию в коде;
Переносить из заголовка текст вопроса в само тело вопроса;
Менять заголовок на более понятный;
Удалять/добавлять в поле "Метки" лишние/отсутствующие метки;
Удалять из заголовка "метки-дубликаты" (если в вопросе есть метки, то они не нужны в заголовке вопроса — их можно убрать оттуда);
Добавлять визуальное пространство между абзацами текста ("разбивать" текст) с целью улучшения чтения;
Добавлять неразрывные пробелы (нажатием клавиш Left ALT + 2-5-5) для улучшения переноса слов и предлогов в тексте;
Представлять информацию в более наглядном виде: переносить текст в таблицу, в списки (маркированные и нумерованные), добавлять курсив и жирный шрифт;
"Пересобирать" вопрос — когда текст ошибки идёт до прилагаемого кода (вы можете поменять местами абзацы текста, если это улучшит восприятие читающего);
Заменять однострочный текст кода/ошибки на блок кода.

Например, заменить это:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod congue dapibus. Aliquam lorem tortor, accumsan non dapibus eget, condimentum a arcu. Curabitur auctor ultricies dignissim. Proin aliquet ante sit amet eros suscipit consequat. Mauris eros dui, feugiat in elit faucibus, dictum venenatis erat. Curabitur posuere lobortis eros, non commodo elit ultrices sed. Suspendisse potenti. Integer eu molestie enim. Phasellus ut elit massa. Donec rhoncus arcu vel sem lacinia varius. Ut facilisis tincidunt imperdiet. Sed a scelerisque eros. Proin aliquam ante non lobortis varius.
На это:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod congue
dapibus. Aliquam lorem tortor, accumsan non dapibus eget, condimentum a arcu. Curabitur 
auctor ultricies dignissim. Proin aliquet ante sit amet eros suscipit consequat. Mauris 
eros dui, feugiat in elit faucibus, dictum venenatis erat. Curabitur posuere lobortis eros, 
non commodo elit ultrices sed. Suspendisse potenti. Integer eu molestie enim. Phasellus ut 
elit massa. Donec rhoncus arcu vel sem lacinia varius. Ut facilisis tincidunt imperdiet. 
Sed a scelerisque eros. Proin aliquam ante non lobortis varius.

Заметьте, что я добавил разрыв строки (с помощью Enter) в конце каждой строки, чтобы не было такого:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod congue dapibus. Aliquam lorem tortor, accumsan non dapibus eget, condimentum a arcu. Curabitur auctor ultricies dignissim. Proin aliquet ante sit amet eros suscipit consequat. Mauris eros dui, feugiat in elit faucibus, dictum venenatis erat. Curabitur posuere lobortis eros, non commodo elit ultrices sed. Suspendisse potenti. Integer eu molestie enim. Phasellus ut elit massa. Donec rhoncus arcu vel sem lacinia varius. Ut facilisis tincidunt imperdiet. Sed a scelerisque eros. Proin aliquam ante non lobortis varius.


Однако стоит помнить о том, что текст ошибки в таких языках программирования, как Python, "позиционно-зависимый". Я говорю про стрелочку, указывающую на ошибку (собственно, как в примере пункта 1 первого заголовка).
Внимательно переносите текст ошибки на новые строки! Если же вы не можете достичь желаемого результата, то не переносите текст ошибки на другие строки вовсе!
Подробнее о правилах форматирования кода читайте в связанной статье "Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?".
3. Процесс принятия предлагаемых правок
На все вопросы были даны ответы в предыдущих пунктах. Осталось ответить на последний вопрос: "Как происходит процесс принятия предлагаемой правки?"
Как было сказано ранее, процессом утверждения предлагаемых правок занимается проверяющий (пользователь с 2 000 и более баллов репутации).
Предлагаемые правки пользователей агрегируются в "Очереди проверок".
Правка утверждается коллективом проверяющих.
Обычно правка принимается/отклоняется по голосованию двух проверяющих. Однако если мнение проверяющих расходится (один проголосовал "Принять", другой проголосовал "Править"), то решающим будет голос третьего проверяющего.
Однако и в этой процедуре есть нюанс: если проверяющие проголосовали против принятия предлагаемой правки, автор вопроса/ответа всё равно может принять предлагаемую правку!
Аналогично и для обратного: автор может отклонить и откатить правку, даже если она была утверждена. Решающее право голоса за автором!
4. Дополнительно
Есть отдельный условный вид предлагаемых правок — "Правка ради правки". Это когда вы меняете в тексте:

Написан код. Он вычисляет с помощью функции <...>

На:

Написал код, который вычисляет по функции <...>

И т. п. незначительные изменения. Пожалуйста, постарайтесь предлагать меньше таких правок — не забивайте очередь проверяющих, освободите место для качественных правок.
Сосредоточьтесь на создании правок, описанных в пункте 2.
"Правками ради правок" можете заняться при достижении репутации в 2 000 баллов, тогда вам уже никто не запретит вносить незначительные правки, которые ничего не меняют (но так вы сможете утолить свою жажду сделать правку ).

Помните, что за принятие правок вы получаете репутацию (+ 2), за удаление вопроса, который вы правили, у вас забирают репутацию (- 2), за откат вашей правки (редактором или автором сообщения) у вас также забирают репутацию (- 2).
Вы можете предложить не более пяти правок! У вас появится возможность сделать ещё одну правку после утверждения хотя бы одной из ваших предложенных правок.
Как видите, внесение хороших правок поощряется сайтом Stack Overflow!
После получения репутации в размере 2 000 баллов вам больше не нужно будет проходить процесс утверждения правок (вы сами становитесь проверяющим), но вам также перестают начисляться баллы за правки.
Вам также перестают начисляться баллы при принятии 500 правок, когда вы суммарно получили за них 1 000 баллов репутации.
Подробнее о том, как работает репутация, вы можете прочитать в справке, в разделе "Что такое репутация? Как можно её заработать (и потерять)?", а также в авторской статье "Что такое репутация и как её заработать?" (да, это дубликат ).

Надеюсь, что мне удалось ответить вам на вопрос "Как стать хорошим редактором", и теперь вы знаете, какие правки предлагать/осуществлять, и что вообще нужно делать редактору 

От меня +1 еще с утра, но как по мне мало внимания данному посту. Написано легко и четко. Ваша работа в Майкрософт - документацию на русском писать.

На счет выделения ошибок. Частенько (особенно в последних версиях пайтон) важно сохранить форматирование ошибки, поскольку питон показывает точное место возникновение ошибки в строке. То есть воспользоваться способом описанным вами не улучшит, а скорей всего ухудшит читабельность. В таких случаях я помещаю ошибку в обычный блок кода без добавлений переводов строк
